# Definite integration of an algebraic expression

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}$$

I think none of the properties of definite integral will be useful here so I think I will have to integrate. But I am unable to do so. Some hints on how to integrate. Thanks.

Comment: Numerical integration yields 1.0472... which you might use as a check on any symbolic solution.

Comment: Looks like $\pi/3$ to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{x+1+x^{-1}}$, we have $2 u du = (1 - x^{-2})dx$ and

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}
= \int_\infty^\sqrt{3} \frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{2u du}{(x-x^{-1})u}
= 2 \int_\sqrt{3}^\infty \frac{du}{x+2+x^{-1}}\\
= 2 \int_\sqrt{3}^\infty \frac{du}{u^2+1}
= 2 \left[\tan^{-1}u\right]_{\sqrt{3}}^\infty
= 2 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* gives the indefinite integral:

$\int {1-x \over 1+x}{1 \over \sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}} dx =$

$-\frac{2 \sqrt[6]{-1} x^{3/2} \left(i \sqrt{1-\frac{(-1)^{2/3}}{x}}
   \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt[3]{-1}}{x}} F\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{(-1)^{5/6}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)|(-1)^{2/3}\right)+\frac{2
   \left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{-1}
   \sqrt{x}-1\right)}} \sqrt{\frac{(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt{x}-1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)}} \sqrt{-\frac{(-1)^{2/3}
   \sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{-1}-1}} \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)^2
   \left(\left(\sqrt[3]{-1}+i\right) F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)}}\right)\right|-3\right)-2 \sqrt[3]{-1} \Pi
   \left(\frac{-3 i+(1+2 i) \sqrt{3}}{(2+i)+\sqrt{3}};\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)}}\right)\right|-3\right)\right)}{x}-\frac{2
   \left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{-1}
   \sqrt{x}-1\right)}} \sqrt{\frac{(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt{x}-1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)}} \sqrt{-\frac{(-1)^{2/3}
   \sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{-1}-1}} \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)^2
   \left(\left(\sqrt[3]{-1}-i\right) F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{x}-1\right)}}\right)\right|-3\right)-2 \sqrt[3]{-1} \Pi
   \left(-\frac{i \left(3+(2+i) \sqrt{3}\right)}{(-2+i)+\sqrt{3}};\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)
   \left(\sqrt[3]{-1}
   \sqrt{x}-1\right)}}\right)\right|-3\right)\right)}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x
   \left(x^2+x+1\right)}}$

which very strongly suggests that there's no simple method "by hand."

You can also do a Taylor series:

$\frac{1-x}{(x+1) \sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{5 \sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{23 x^{3/2}}{8}-\frac{37
   x^{5/2}}{16}+\frac{203 x^{7/2}}{128}-\frac{355 x^{9/2}}{256}+O\left(x^{11/2}\right)$

and then integrate each term, but that will likely not give an adequate solution.

Comment: the result can not expressed by a known elementary function.

Comment: Does Mathematica give a result for the definite integral? I doubt the result will be elementary, but the presence of the elliptic integrals in that answer makes me hope that the final result can be expressed using complete elliptic integrals.

Comment: Okay, so how do i proceed?

Comment: Use computer algebra.  (I don't know why anyone is doing this kind of work "by hand" anymore, just as I don't know why anyone would multiply two 20-digit numbers by hand now that there are calculators.)